# URLs for images in tweets

Tags: python

I have a list that contains URLs to a lot of tweets, e.g. https://twitter.com/EmilBakke/status/1264250412120649729
From each tweet in this list I want to extract the image URLs (e.g. https://pbs.twimg.com/media/EYuFC_PX0AA6_KB?format=jpg&name=small) into a list of URLs, and then download the images from the image URL to my local machine. Ideally, the filename of the images would be the tweet ID that the image is linked to.

I have not used the Twitter API to obtain the list of tweet URLs, hence I cannot use Media Entities, and do not know if a specific tweet contains images or not.

My initial idea was to use BeautifulSoup to obtain the image URLs. I have figured out that the image URL is in contained in this HTML snippet:
`<img alt="Image" draggable="true" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/EYuFC_PX0AA6_KB?format=jpg&amp;name=small" class="css-9pa8cd" title="" style="">` However, I cannot seem to actually extract the URL into a list.

Here is what I have so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html_page = urlopen("https://twitter.com/EmilBakke/status/1264250412120649729").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
for link in soup.findAll('img class', attrs={'src': re.compile("^https://")}):
    print(link.get('src'))
```

Running this returns nothing, but I cannot figure out, what I am doing wrong. Also, I need to figure out a way to loop through all links in the list of links. Help will be appreciated!

Comment: I think you should findAll just img, not 'img class'.

Comment: Thanks for answering! That doesn't return anything either though.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter prevents accessing their website if it doesn't detect JavaScript enabled. A workaround would be to use Selenium + Beautiful Soup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

browser = webdriver.Firefox()  
browser.get('https://twitter.com/EmilBakke/status/1264250412120649729')  
time.sleep(1)
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
imgTags = soup.findAll('img')
```